# how to abort the execution of the cogs command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I had a code without cogs. There I could abort the execution of the command if it was sent in the wrong channel.
after switching to cogs, the method no longer works.
Can you tell me how to do it correctly?

```
from discord.ext import commands

class message_bot(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return

        if message.channel.id == 53508131586375336832:

            print('no channel')
            return
        else:
            await self.bot.process_commands(message)

def setup(bot):
   bot.add_cog(message_bot(bot))
```

Comment: Can you please post more of your code? We need the minimum needed to recreate the problem. Thanks.

Comment: corrected it...

Comment: Is the indentation correct? You need to indent the `bot.add_cog(message_bot(bot))`

Comment: the indentation in the code is correct, I corrected it on the site

Answer (score 0):

Add 'on_message' to you listener arguments

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class message_bot(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener('on_message')
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return

        if message.channel.id == 53508131586375336832:

            print('no channel')
            return
        else:
            await self.bot.process_commands(message)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(message_bot(bot))
```

*classmethod listener(name=None)
A decorator that marks a function as a listener.
This is the cog equivalent of Bot.listen().
Parameters
name (str) – The name of the event being listened to. If not provided, it defaults to the function’s name.*

Sorry about my last answer, I missed something in your questions ;)

Comment: I just want the command not to be executed in this chat, but it is executed regardless of on_message

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry about my last one :) this should work

Comment: the code prints print ('no channel')
but executes the command in the chat
I don't understand how to leave it under this condition

Comment: the funny thing is that the code works if you use it in the file where the token is defined

Comment: @etozhesandy The code works on my end within ./cogs/message_bot.py But, you need to load the cogs in the main using bot.load_extension(path)

Comment: in any case, thank you for trying to help